# How do I inherit from multiple classes with different __init__ inputs?

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm hoping to inherit from two different classes that have different inputs into their `__init__` methods.  How do I properly inherit from them both?

Below is a simple example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hello")


class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("World")


class c:
    def __init__(self, text):
        print(text)


class d(a, c):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Kronos')  # <-- This breaks (and understandably so)
```

---

While similar to many other questions of multiple inheritance (i.e. [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)), I'm looking for how to inherit from multiple classes with different inputs to their `__init__`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: consider adding an `*args, **kwargs` to your `__init__` methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can do it like below

```
class d(a,c):
   def__init__(self,text):
       a.__init__(self)
       c.__init__(self,text)
```

Comment: Ah, there we go.  Yes that's what I'm looking for.  For those interested, this not only executes the `print` statements, but if you were to have properties or methods they are properly inherited.

Comment: I would also reverse the a and c in execution.  With the `super` method the `__mro__` order is left to right.  Meaning that if I had a property defined in `a` and `c`, `a` would resolve the property first I believe.

Comment: This (unlike super) will not guarantee that each class in the inheritance tree is only initialized once. Look at the examples [here](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). Specifically the _Practical_Advice_, and either make them all have the same interface, or accept kwargs.

Comment: yes i think there is a better way with super but i dont remember why it is better and since i cant test it right now i edited to this one

Comment: @ChadS. correct, but if you inherit in the reversed shown order, it should resolve similar to that of super.  Execution time and memory management may take a hit.

Comment: @KronoS If you have classes A, B(A), C(B), D(A, C), your method will execute A's `__init__` twice. super() wont.

Comment: @ChadS. yes I agree.  The accepted answer does not protect against roundtripping.